# Riak Server Returning Error 404

Tags: riak

I've installeld Riak 2 on a Centos 6 box and I've managed to boot Riak but now get this error when I try to test it:

```
curl -v http://<hostname>:8098/types/default/props
* About to connect() to <hostname> port 8098 (#0)
*   Trying <hostname>... connected
* Connected to <hostname> (<hostname>) port 8098 (#0)
> GET /types/default/props HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: <hostname>:8098
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Object Not Found
< Server: MochiWeb/1.1 WebMachine/1.10.0 (never breaks eye contact)
< Date: Fri, 21 Aug 2015 01:02:48 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 193
< 
* Connection #0 to host <hostname> left intact
* Closing connection #0
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>404 Not Found</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>Not Found</H1>The requested document was not found on this server.<P><HR><ADDRESS>mochiweb+webmachine web server</ADDRESS></BODY></HTML>[root@riak1 ~]#
```

Also I did modify my apps.config and vm like so:
 {pb, [ {"", 8087 } ]}
 {http, [ {"", 8098 } ]},
-name riak@

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Do you have an ip address set in your app.config settings ?

Comment: Also what does `curl -v http://<hostname>:8098/stats` return?

Comment: Did you already create and activate a bucket type?  I don't think the bucket type functionality is active until you do.